# Show an initial value for file/image upload in rendered Django form

Tags: python, html, django, forms

So I'm uploading an image and a document. The problem is two fold, first in the rendered form it is showing the label but not the initial value or even a picture so its hard for anyone to realize that they have to upload anything. Secondly, upon uploading its not showing the document/image that has been uploaded so you end up thinking it didn't work. I've attached a picture below showing the issue. How do I fix this?

[image]
[picture showing the problem in the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ7hX.png)

The above picture clearly shows the problem at hand.

As of 31/08/17 I've added Meta and tried using the `ClearableFileInput` widget but still not working. See below for the updated code:

from forms.py

```
profile_image = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(), required=True, label="Profile Picture*")
    cvv = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(), initial='upload a CV', required=True, label="CV*")

    class Meta:
        model = ProfileTeacher
        fields = ('description', 'document' 'name','last_name','phone_number', 'date_of_birth', 'bank_account', 'id_number', 'postal_code', 'adress', 'profile_image', 'nationality' )
        widgets = {
            'profile_image' : forms.FileInput,
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterFormTeacher, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'John'
        self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Doe'
        self.fields['adress'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = '4 Privet Drive, Little Whinging'
```

from models.py

```
models.ImageField(upload_to=teacher_directory_path,
                                  null = True,
                                  blank=True,
                                  default='/perfil.png')
cvv = models.FileField(upload_to=teacher_directory_path, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name="CV")
```

from the html that renders the form:

```
<div class="card-content">
<form id="teacher-register-form" action="{% url 'teacher-register' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form|bootstrap }}
   <span></span>
   <br/>
   <br/><!-- an attempt to bridge the gap between the buttons. -->
   <span>{% trans "If you have an account" %}</span>
   <br />
   <a href="{% url 'teacher-login' %}" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans "Init session" %}</a>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">{% trans "Register" %}</button>
</form>
```

I must add, in the models when in admin everything is showing fine but when rendering then I dont see anyvalue.

Comment: You should also show the template, specifically, the way you render the form.

Comment: Browsers don't let you do this, for security reasons.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil I've added the html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358356/django-forms-filefield-initial-value

Comment: @DanielRoseman that can't be right since I've seen this implement before. I simply want to show a place holder so people know there is something needed there and to click on it. Right now, as shown in the picture its just white space. When you click on it starts the upload process but no one would know you should do that.

Comment: @Ashish so that means I can't even show text like "upload your cv'?

Comment: Can't I add an image or button or some sort of visual aid so people know there is something that needs to be uploaded?

Comment: How did you solved this? @fmakawa