# Using Django form FileField with custom file

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I'm creating a form builder for my project. It builds forms dynamically according to fields specified in database. There are 3 tables: form, form fields and form fields values. Now I'm trying to bind data from form values to form fields. It works well, for example like this:

```
if (field.field_type == 'long_text'):
                new_field = forms.CharField(label=field.label, initial = value, required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

But this doesn't work for FileField:

```
new_field = forms.FileField(label=field.label, required = False, initial = initialData)
```

As far as I understand, "initial" data has to be in certain format: this has to be an object with url and name attributes

This is what I do:

```
try:
    ''' data is stored in JSON {url:'', name:''} format '''
    valueData = json.loads(value)
    initialData.initial = valueData['name']
    initialData.url = valueData['url']
    initialData.name = valueData['url']                        
except:
    pass

new_field = forms.FileField(label=field.label, required = False, initial = initialData)
```

Form is still empty. No "clear" checkbox, no url to click and "no file selected".

What can I do to make this file input work? Do I need to emulate model's filefield?

Answer (score 1):

There is similar question with a bit confusing answer: [Django - forms.FileField() initial value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358356/django-forms-filefield-initial-value)

So just to make it easier for other people to solve similar problem, finally I came up with the following solution:

```
class DummyFile:
    def __init__(self, url, name):
        self.url = url; self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

(...)

```
valueData = json.loads(value)
initialData = DummyFile("%s%s" % (settings.MEDIA_URL,valueData['url']), valueData['name'])
new_field = forms.FileField(label=field.label, required = False, initial = initialData)
```

So it basically creates new class, that has `.url` value that returns path to actual file and also `__str__` that converts object to filename string. I use url and name separate, because file names are hashed when saved to server and then database stores real name of the file.