# How to load an initial value for a ClearableFileInput / FileField (before form is bound)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

How do I set an initial value for a FileField that will display in a ClearableFileInput widget when creating a new object (unbound form)?

I have tried the following but `widget.value` does not return a `FeildFile` instance if it is the first time the user is creating the object:

models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfile=models.FileField()
```

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['myfile'].initial= 'myfile.pdf'

    class Meta:
        model = Issuer
        fields = ['myfile']
```

This results in :

[image]

Similarly, setting a default value in the modelfield does not work:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfile=models.FileField(default='myfile.pdf')
```

The widget initial value is still `None`, but if it is left empty and saved the file object `myfile.pdf` **will** be created. The `settings.MEDIA_URL` and `urls.py` is definitely correct and the file is on the system because it is loaded after form save.

What I am missing is showing it as an initial value before a form is saved and an object created.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18502983/2429989) answer suggests you can't provide initial data but you can provide an initial value with a `url` attribute to fake the appearance of a file. It's not clear how you would do this though.

Trying to create an initial file object in the form also returns `widget.value = None`

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    f_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR + settings.MEDIA_URL, 'myfile.pdf')

    f = open(f_path)
    myfile = File(f)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['privacy_policy'].initial = self.myfile
```

Comment: You're quite close on your last block of code, Is it really your running code? In this case I suggest you move the opening and `File()` instanciation to the init method.

Comment: Honestly, I think this is bad UX. If I get distracted, come back to the form and scan the form for missing fields, I think I've already filled it in. It's much easier to provide a help_text, that says "if you don't upload anything, we will use this document". Or make it explicit, with a "use default" / "use custom" radio that enables the file input. This is even more important if you get into legal documents.

Answer (score 2):

Your last block of code is quite close.

You are actually telling the user through the `ClearableFileInput` widget that if the user does not input anything in the file input, the initial value will be your pdf file.

*But*, this is only for display, you have to actually put the logic when you save the instance! (FileField won't do it for you) So the right thing is to override the `save()` method of your form, and in the case of a creation, put the actual file as the value. Like this:

```py
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'myfile.pdf')

        self.default_file = open(path)

        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['privacy_policy'].initial = File(self.default_file)
        self.fields['privacy_policy'].initial.url = default_storage.url('myfile.pdf')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Actually put the default file as a value if no input for creation
        if not self.instance.pk and not self.cleaned_data.get('privacy_policy'):
            self.instance.privacy_policy = self.default_file
            self.instance.privacy_policy._committed = True
        super().save(commit)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very close. I think it requires `path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR + settings.MEDIA_URL, 'default_privacy_policy.pdf')` in order to access the file, however using `default_storage.url()` means that `widget.value` displays as `/usr/src/app/media/default_privacy_policy.pdf` whereas the default behaviour for other files already saved in the same `media/` path display simply as `myfile.pdf` (without the path reference). Is there a way to replicate this?

Comment: The other issue is this will save with `default_privacy_policy_O7eQSVu.pdf`, presumable because it's avoiding overwriting the same file. As the file already exists, I just want to link to this rather than have the cost of another file write. Is this possible?

Comment: As for the URL, check that `MEDIA_URL` is set to an actual url (cf documentation), and `MEDIA_ROOT` as a filesystem path . As for the renaming of the file, yes, it does that because it already exists. You can maybe bypass by setting `_committed = True` but I haven't tested it, I've updated the code in my answer.

Comment: This did it for me. I was trying to show an image of a related model instance on insert. setting initial, and initial.url as you showed here did it. Saving works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
The only way to set the value of a file input is by the user to select it.
This is done for security reasons. Otherwise, you would be able to create a Javascript that automatically uploads a specific file from the client's computer.
it has nothing to with Django (model, form) its a browser feature, we only do the things with Django form if it is possible in Html and javascript.

your form:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

f_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR + settings.MEDIA_URL, 'myfile.pdf')

f = open(f_path)
myfile = File(f)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['privacy_policy'].value = self.myfile
```

the default ClearableFileField template is

```
{% if widget.is_initial %}{{ widget.initial_text }}: <a href="{{ widget.value.url }}">{{ widget.value }}</a>{% if not widget.required %}
<input type="checkbox" name="{{ widget.checkbox_name }}" id="{{ widget.checkbox_id }}">
<label for="{{ widget.checkbox_id }}">{{ widget.clear_checkbox_label }}</label>{% endif %}<br>
{{ widget.input_text }}:{% endif %}
<input type="{{ widget.type }}" name="{{ widget.name }}"{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>
```

The widget `is_initial` should be true to see the link.

```
class ClearableFileInput(FileInput):
    ...

    def is_initial(self, value):
        """
        Return whether value is considered to be initial value.
        """
        return bool(value and getattr(value, 'url', False))

     ....
```

Comment: Hi man, you would know, which causes the initial value to become a True or False and how i can force it? My context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70772754/currently-file-upload-is-not-present-in-modeladmin-change-page

Answer (score 0):

I have managed set a ClearableFileInput by creating a model with the custom url and then setting specifying that model as the instance.

In your example it would be something like this (untested):

```py
model = MyModel(myfile='abc.txt')
form = MyForm(instance=model)
```

However, I have found that if you have FILES included in the form (i.e.: MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=model)` the FILES takes precedence.

I have found this very finicky, so hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

***From Django Documentation***

**FileField.upload_to**

This attribute provides a way of setting the upload directory and **file name**, and can be set in two ways. In both cases, the value is passed to the Storage.save() method.

If you specify a string value or a Path, it may contain strftime() formatting, which will be replaced by the date/time of the file upload (so that uploaded files don’t fill up the given directory). For example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/uploads
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')
    # or...
    # file will be saved to MEDIA_ROOT/uploads/2015/01/30
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

For example, say your MEDIA_ROOT is set to '/home/media', and upload_to is set to 'photos/%Y/%m/%d'. The '%Y/%m/%d' part of upload_to is strftime() formatting; '%Y' is the four-digit year, '%m' is the two-digit month and '%d' is the two-digit day. **If you upload a file on Jan. 15, 2007, it will be saved in the directory /home/media/photos/2007/01/15.**