# Django Edit Form not showing the attachment link

Tags: django, django-forms

Good Afternoon,

I have a query when trying to create an edit template, I'm retrieving data via an api call. When I input the data in the django form.Forms the attachment is showing as blank.

This is the Form.py file

```
class PaymentListForm(forms.Form):

  Title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
  Receipt_Amount = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
  Request_Amount = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
  Receipt_Attachment = forms.FileField()

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PaymentListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And this is the views.py file

```
def edit_payments(request, trn_pk):
    trns = get_transaction_by_id(trn_pk)
    data = trns['data']
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = PaymentListForm(initial=data)
        return render(request, 'paymentlist/createeditpayments.html', {'form': form})
```

I can confirm that in the data dictionary there is the link for the attachment but somehow in the forms the attachment is getting lost.

Any help reg this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358356/django-forms-filefield-initial-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no possibility to set initial value for FileField like in CharField or DecimalField but there is a way to solve this problem. What we need is to hide forms.FileField and handle loading files by a label and show initial data as just text. so first hide forms.FileField:

**forms.py**:

```
class PaymentListForm(forms.Form):
  Title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
  Receipt_Amount = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
  Request_Amount = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
  Receipt_Attachment = forms.FileField(label="", widget=forms.FileInput(
      attrs={'style': "display: none",},
  ), )

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PaymentListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

now we need to add  tag to handle uploading files instead forms.FileField and  tag where we'll display info about attachment url. I'm not sure how html template looks exactly so i've made some generic one - important  tag we need to place inside  tag.

**createeditpayments.html**:

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}

   {{ form.as_p }}

   <span>Receipt attachment: </span>  
   <label for="id_Receipt_Attachment" class="mt-2 btn btn-primary " style="cursor: pointer;">Choose file...</label>
   <span id="receipt_url"> {{ url_of_receipt }}</span>
   <br><br>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" role="button" type="submit">
     Save
   </button>
```

so we should get such output:
[image]
of course u can style label, span as u want to. now we need to change a bit the view - specially to add to context dictionary `url_of_receipt`.

**views.py**:

```
def edit_payments(request, trn_pk):
    trns = get_transaction_by_id(trn_pk)
    data = trns['data']
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = PaymentListForm(initial=data)
        return render(request, 'paymentlist/createeditpayments.html', {'form': form, 'url_of_receipt': data['Receipt_Attachment']})
```

i've assumed that `data` is a dictionary with such structure:

```
        data = {
            'Title': 'Example title',
            'Receipt_Amount': 21.99,
            'Request_Amount': 34,
            'Receipt_Attachment': 'media/example.receipt.pdf' 
        }
```

so now we've got such output:
[image]
and very last thing is to switch on uploading files after clicking the label. think the best way is to use jQuery and short script. so i the bottom of createeditpayments.html place such code:
**createeditpayments.html**

```
{% block javascript %}
    <script>
        // fetch url from hidden FieldField and insert it next to upload button
        $("#id_Receipt_Attachment").change(function () {
            {#readURL(this);#}
            $('#receipt_url').text(' ' + this.files[0].name);
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

and in base.html (or any html which `createeditpayments.html` extends) place just above  closing tag:

**base.html:**

```
 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    {% block javascript %}{% endblock %}

</body>
```

now the label should upload files and change url next to it.
[image]
[image]